# Team using git/git-svn to share work and only occasional svn commits

Tags: git-svn

I am new to git but read this [article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/VersionControlTools.html#MultipleVcs) by Martin Fowler where he describes a setup where a team works using git/git-svn and only occasionally commit to the central svn repo. 
Can somebody point to an article or screen-cast (or off course answer how to do this) describing the workflow, commands and pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://blog.emmanuelbernard.com/2010/05/git-how-my-life-has-improved-since-last-month-when-i-used-svn/comment-page-1/#comment-2248

The summary is that you have one repo with git-svn. Everybody who wants to work with git just clones that repository and works with plain git. Than on the git-svn repo somebody from time to time fetches commits from subversion, merges new commits from git and dcommits them back to svn (rolled up, it's not possible to transfer individual commits both ways).